# Why there is very large difference between cross validation scores?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, cross-validation

I have a very simple regression model and I am doing the cross validation. When cv=10 the highest score i got is 60.3 and lowest is -9.7 which is useless. Average will be 30.

No of row data set= 658

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If those are R2 values, it's likely just a bad model fit. I would try leave-one-out CV. Set cv=658 and find average and 95% confidence interval, if its still bad, review your model, depending on the accuracy of your model when trained on all the data you either have under or over fitting